# mySQL regex in the where clause

Tags: mysql, regex

```
SELECT telephone_number
FROM table
WHERE telephone_number REGEXP '^1[() -]*999[() -]*999[() -]*9999$';
```

how do i make so its valid for any number format and any number
like

```
407-888-0909
1(408)998-7654
7776654433
876-7788
```

right now its only valid for 1-999-999-9999

Comment: What do you mean by "any number format"? Do you mean any string that contains at least one digit?

Comment: yes but without the "()-" and the spaces

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL regex at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451567/mysql-regex-at-runtime)

Comment: If speed is at all important, you should clean the data in the database and avoid using a regex. :-)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT telephone_number
  FROM table
 WHERE telephone_number REGEXP '^1[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{4}$';
```

Reference:

- [Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: what if i have a value 6309991234 but in the database its in (630)9991234 can i add a REGEXP '^1[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{3}[() -]*[[:digit:]]{4}$'="6309991234"

Comment: @John: The brackets support "m,n", so you could use {3,7} to capture "9991234".  I'm still messing with the functionality to get optional character support working...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT telephone_number
  FROM table
 WHERE telephone_number REGEXP '[1]?[(]?[[:DIGIT:]]{3}[)]?[-]?[[:DIGIT:]]{3}[-]?[[:DIGIT:]]{4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very wise to store phone numbers in a database with spaces, dashes, parentheses, etc.  The most efficient way is to truncate all that garbage to a simple 10 digit number.  That way you can actually store the number in an INTEGER based column instead of a VARCHAR.

Comment: I am not doing the insert so i just need to pull out

Comment: This can also be problematic when you need to store a leading 0 for the exchange. Not that he leads to that requirement above.

Comment: Use VARCHAR but sanitize it before insertion (e.g. get rid of spaces/dashes/...)