# Update MySQL table & Regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a MySQL table with 4 millions of records having a field like "hello@xyz.com22-03-2015". Concatenated date is not fixed for all 4 million records. I am wondering how can I remove the numbers or any string after @xyz using mysql. One possible solution must be somehow with Regular expression and I know that Mysql does not allow replace using regex, so I am wondering how this particular task can be completed. I want to remove everything after @xyz.com

Many thanks

Comment: There is no `@xyz.com`

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp?

Comment: not yet @jmargolisvt. I thought maybe we can find another solution before getting into that. Is that the only things you think works?

Comment: I'm not a mysql expert, but it seems that would help you get it done in one shot.  You can [select by regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452572/mysql-regex-in-the-where-clause).  But to replace, it [seems like a good tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql).

Comment: SQL can't solve all problems; use Perl/PHP/VB/Java/...

Comment: I think Php can better do the job ;-)