# How can I transform an "Or" SQL condition in LIKE Syntax (REGEX)?

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to write the following statement without the SQL OR:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE names LIKE 'john%' OR names LIKE 'brian%'
```

So, I don't want to use OR because the names in my real problem are too many, but I also don't want to use REGEXP. How is the LIKE syntax? Thank you in advance!

I don't want to use REGEXP because some names are in square brackets and others or not. And this make it too complicated. I just want to know if there is a syntax similar to 'REGEXP '^(".implode("|", $names_array).")[[:>:]]'";' using LIKE

Comment: If you want records of people whose name start with John or Brian, I think your query is just fine. Make sure you index names field

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL regex in the where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452572/mysql-regex-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: no, I said in the question, I have many names saved in an array. If I used REGEXP I would do this with implode and | as an OR. Something like this:  'REGEXP '^(".implode("|", $names_array).")[[:>:]]'";' But I need a similar syntax for LIKE

Comment: What about: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEFT(names, 4) = 'john' OR LEFT(names, 5) = 'brian'` as this should cover your needs?

Comment: Why do you want to use `LIKE` and not `REGEXP`? You cannot do what you want with `LIKE`, [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) only have `_` (one character) and `%` (any characters) symbol, you won't be able to create anything similar to a `OR` using `LIKE`.

Comment: You should make other entity for search if you need to pass `too many names`, something like namegroups... It depends from your business logic

Comment: Be careful with `or` requests and `rlike` requests, since they would not use teh index (if you have one). This means long query times if the table is big.

Comment: Another thing: If you allow user input to contain special characters, be VERY careful about SQL-Injection!

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEX`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
  WHERE `names`
  REGEX '^(john|brian)+'
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but won't this only match names like "john" "johnjohn" "brianjohnbrian" etc ?

Comment: @Emi1305, no `^$` anchors here. So, 111john222 matches too.

Comment: Correct regex is `^(john|brian)`