# How do I select a json column with such a structure for Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, json, select, mysql-5.7

I have a products table with the following attributes in my mysql5.7 database table **Products**

- id : Integer
- attributes : Json Type
- price

I have inserted the following record:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `attributes`, `name`, `cost_price`,
`selling_price`) VALUES (NULL, '{\"size\": [{\"value\": \"M\"},
{\"value\": \"L\"}], \"test\": 1, \"color\": [\"black\", \"maroon\",
\"orange\"]}', 'P2', '10', '20');
```

Here is the json value for the column:

> {"size": [{"value": "M"}, {"value": "L"}], "test": 1, "color":
>   ["black", "maroon", "orange"]}

How do i get records of data that has size:L? How do I do a sql query in Mysql? I tried this and it does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` where attributes->>'$.size[*].value'='M'
```

Hope someone could help me to understand as I am pity new to Json structure in mysql. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `REGEXP`? [How to use regexp in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452572/mysql-regex-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: how does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it and I believe this is a possible query:

```
select * from products where json_contains(attributes, '{"size":{"value" : "XL"}}');
```